# How to avoid using relative path imports (/../../../redux/action/action1) in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app, relative-path, absolute-path

I've been using create-react-app package for creating a react website. I was using relative paths throughout my app for importing components, resources, redux etc. eg, `import action from '../../../redux/action`

I have tried using [module-alis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) npm package but with no success. Is there any plugin that I can use to import based on the folder name or alias i.e. an absolute path?

Eg., `import action from '@redux/action'` or `import action from '@resource/css/style.css'`

Comment: Two years on, CRA now has a new approach to configuring absolute imports. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195974/203371).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Create a file called `.env` in the project root and write there:

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

Then restart the development server. You should be able to import anything inside `src` without relative paths.

Note I would not recommend calling your folder `src/redux` because now it is confusing whether `redux` import refers to your app or the library. Instead you can call your folder `src/app` and import things from `app/...`.

We intentionally don't support custom syntax like `@redux` because it's not compatible with Node resolution algorithm.

Comment: Can I do this in react-create-app? I tried, but it seem not to work, although guy from here https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d suggest the same

Comment: @Mehari what's your version of create-react-app and react-scripts?

Comment: @qwang create-react-app-1.4.3 & react-scripts-1.0.14

Comment: More details about implementation can be found here - https://youtu.be/xHiCRpfZIO8

Comment: This works for us locally but not when we're building in Jenkins (we have a React-app within a Node-app), anyway, we got around this problem to add this to React's package.json instead:
{"scripts": {"build": "NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts build"}}
Now the build works in our Jenkins setup as well. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Currently, create-react-app is showing a deprecated warning if you use this approach. The recommended way is now to use a jsConfig.json file: `{  "compilerOptions": { "baseUrl": "src" }  }`

Comment: More information about Agustin's comment found here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports

Comment: Two questions: (1) I'm having a hard time importing a folder with index.js. It won't implicitly understand to point to index.js to find the exports. (2) Can we customize the alias of the absolute import?

Comment: think of the unfortunate new developer who starts working on your code base and has to deal with the ambiguity of npm packages vs folder names!!

Comment: that option is depricated and should not be used...

Answer (score 113):

The approach in the accepted answer has now been superseded. Create React App now has a different way to set absolute paths as documented [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports).

To summarise, you can configure your application to support importing modules using absolute paths by doing the following:

Create/Edit your jsconfig.json/tsconfig.json in the root of your project with the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Once you have done this you can then import by specifying subdirectories of "src" (in the following example, components is a subdirectory of src) e.g.

```
import Button from 'components/Button'
```

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component

Comment: @VigneshwaranChandrasekaran that link is already included in my answer. See "...way to set absolute paths as documented [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports)."

Comment: I like this solution better. 

Comment: I really won't choose this solution. It allows aliases for all your `/src` subfolder structure. This could create many design and dependency problems on the writing of all future components by hiding its dependencies in favor of a minimalist import.

We must choose wisely what can be aliased and what can be not.

Comment: Just to clarify, `baseUrl` is not specific to Create React App but is a general typescript setting, so should work in other scenarios - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl

Answer (score 6):

We can use webpack 2 resolve property in the webpack config.

**Sample webpack config using resolve :**

Here component and utils are independent folder containing React components.

```
resolve: {
        modules: ['src/scripts', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
        unsafeCache: true,
        alias: {
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scripts', 'components'),
            utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scripts', 'utils'),
        }
    }
```

**After that we can import directly in files :**

```
import UiUtils from 'utils/UiUtils';
import TabContent from 'components/TabContent';
```

[Webpack 2 Resolve Reference](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Comment: I use create-react-app package where i cannot modify the webpack config. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: webpack.config.js is available in below path :

`/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js`

`/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js`

Comment: No, it is not supported to modify these configs. You can eject but then you lose many benefits of CRA. Please see my answer for a supported way of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

After you try [Ben Smith's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195974/203371) above if you find eslint complains about importing absolute path add the following line to your eslint config:

```
settings: {
  'import/resolver': {
    node: {
      paths: ['src'],
    },
  },
},
```

replace 'src' with your folder if you use your own boilerplate with your folder's name.

Comment: Cheers for the reference and +1 for getting eslint to work nicely with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` in `package.json` and configure next:

### **react-app-rewired**

```js
// config-overrides.js
const {aliasWebpack, aliasJest} = require('react-app-alias')

const options = {} // default is empty for most cases

module.exports = aliasWebpack(options)
module.exports.jest = aliasJest(options)
```

### craco

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

### all

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Feb 2010
Wasted about an hour on this.
An example is below:

Goal: **Import `App.css` in `HomePage.js`**

> myapp\src\**App.css**
> myapp\src\**pages\HomePage.js**

File: `jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

File: `src\pages\HomePage.js`

```
import "App.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) for my project to resolve that problem.
**babel-plugin-module-resolver** also is the same as **module-alis**. So I think you should just resolve using **module-alis** problem.

Because you didn't tell us why using **module-alis** was fail? So i cant show you how to fix it.

Dont give up your solution while you dont know the reason!

Comment: This won't work with Create React App. It does not support custom Babel plugins.

Answer (score 1):

in package.json file,

eject this code in the scripts object like this..

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
     "eject": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts eject"
  },
```

this will enable the absolute path imports in your app

Comment: This gave me a lead how to fix our "react-scripts build". See my comment in @dan-abramov 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214138/2986873). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. Some didn't work at all and others worked but the import was already inside `src`, for example:

`import something from 'path/to/file'`.

Whereas I wanted to be able to do:

`import something from 'src/path/to/file'`

Here is how I solved it:

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDirs": [
      "src"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```