# How to add import shortcuts - alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've created a brand new react app

```
create-react-app demo
```

I need to create alias for some directories/components like:

```
import { Header } from '@uicomponents'
```

Where `@uicomponents`  is shortcut for the path '`src/hello/this/is/the/path/to/ui/components` '

All online tutorials telling that I can use alias imports using `resolve.alias`, but I'm wondering how to do this with brand-new react app?

Theres is no .babelrc  or webpack.config.js  files.

Any help please?

Comment: why not add a .babelrc to the project?

Comment: @MurtazaZaidi it's not working, I got the following error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'messagesComponents/Message' in '/Projects/widget/src/store/reducers'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using relative path imports (/../../../redux/action/action1) in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213279/how-to-avoid-using-relative-path-imports-redux-action-action1-in-cre)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032522/eslint-complains-about-typescripts-path-aliasing

Answer (score 14):

If you haven't ejected your application from CRA, then you can alias your source directory with using `NODE_PATH` in your `.env` file. `NODE_PATH=/src/hello/this/is/the/path/to/ui/components`.

If you alias without ejecting, it won't allow you to do the @uicomponents or have multiple aliases. Here's an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2188) on GitHub that talks about it and the relevant [CRA page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) on environment variables.

If you have ejected you can set the alias in the Webpack configuration files and be able to import like you want:

```
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@uicomponents': '/src/hello/this/is/the/path/to/ui/components'
  }
},
...
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED:**

I recommend you to use [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

It allows you to customize `webpack` / `babel` / any other tool that used in `react-scripts` internally.

`Webpack` and `Jest` aliases is not an exception.

And recently I created a plugin called `craco-alias` specially for these purposes.

Links: [GitHub](https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-alias).

This plugin generates webpack and jest aliases for you automatically.

You just need to install [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), write a small config for it, then create (or edit) your `jsconfig.json` / `tsconfig.json` (it works with TS as well) and specify aliases `source` in `craco-alias` config object.

It's easy - you can find all examples on README page.

Of course it works with every command (`npm start`, `npm test`, `run build build`) and allows to pass any CLI arguments.

But, the only problem is that plugin only supports path aliasing, and it doesn't work with module aliases properly.

I hope it will help somebody :)

Answer (score 3):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` with `craco` in *package.json* and configure next:

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```