# How to remove path from import filenames in react for NPM build

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, build, create-react-app

I like to keep my files in organized folders in my project. For example, having an Auth folder for auth-related components, a Components folder for reusable components, a Profile folder for user profile-related components, etc.

Rather than having to either alias all of my folders whenever I create a new one, or have to reference the complete file path for all of my imports, I'd like to be able to declare something as simply as:

```
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';
```

I imagine this can be done with some sort of pre-compile command to flatten the src directory structure into a new folder that just contains all of my files, but I don't know how to do that (or if there's a better method for doing so).

I'm also aware that this will likely mean my filenames need to be unique, which is not a problem for me.

Comment: I think you have to compile all your components in a `build.js` file with gulpjs or gruntjs or webpack

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132624/how-to-add-import-shortcuts-alias

Answer (score 2):

You can use Webpack's `resolve.alias`. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

> Create aliases to import or require certain modules more easily.

Example:

```
// webpack.config.js (or whatever)
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/')
    }
  }
};
```

Now you could type e.g. `import Foo from 'Utilities/Foo'` and it would be as if you had typed the full path name of the module (`src/utilities/Foo`)