# React: Failed to import a JavaScript class from a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React project and this is my first time using it.
I have a JavaScript in the container that import a JavaScript within the components.

This is my containers file

**Restorans.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Restoran from "./components/Restoran/Restoran";
import classes from "./Restorans.module.css";


class Restorans extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            restorans:
                [
                    {id:1, nama: "Restoran A", alamat: "This is address Restoran A", nomorTelepon : "0217352333"},
                    {id:2, nama: "Restoran B", alamat: "This is address Restoran B", nomorTelepon : "0217352334"},
                    {id:3, nama: "Restoran C", alamat: "This is address Restoran C", nomorTelepon : "0217352335"}
                ],
            isLoading: true


        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount()");
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log("shouldComponentUpdate()");
    }

    loadingHandler = () => {
        const curretIsLoading = this.state.isLoading;
        this.setState({isLoading: !(curretIsLoading)});
        console.log(this.state.isLoading);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("render()")
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={classes.Title}> All Restoran </div>
                <div className={classes.Restorans}>
                    {this.state.restorans.map(restoran =>
                    <Restoran 
                        key={restoran.id}
                        nama={restoran.nama}
                        alamat={restoran.alamat}
                        nomorTelepon = {restoran.nomorTelepon}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

}

export default Restorans;
```

and this is my components

**Restoran.js**

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Restoran.module.css";

const Restoran = props => {
    return(
        <div className={classes.Restoran}>
            <h3>
                {props.name}
            </h3>
            <p>
                Alamat: {props.alamat}
            </p>
            <p>
                Nomor Telepon: {props.nomorTelepon}
            </p>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Restoran;
```

My folder library is as follow

[image]

When I run `npm start` on my terminal. I receive this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Restoran/Restoran' in 'C:\Users\[REDACTED]\projectreact\frontend-projectreact\src\containers\Restorans'
```

To my own understanding, there shouldn't be any error. I tried to add `.js` on the end but it still has the same problem. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are within the `containers` directory in `Restorans.js`.

If you want to access `Restoran.js` from `components`, you have to go two levels up and out of `containers`, so change your import in `containers/Restorans.js` to:

```
import Restoran from "./../../components/Restoran/Restoran";
```

The `../../` part will take you to the root parent directory where both `containers` and `components` live as children/sub-directories by moving you up two folders.

As far as CSS, I usually import it one place from in the root `<App/>` component after a normalizer/CSS Reset.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,(just an advice) try not to name your files same. I see Restorans.module.css both in Restoran and Restorans. It might get clumsy to do so. And next thing is if you want to import css file

```
import "../Restoran/Restoran.module.css"
```

or any specific element then

```
import {classes} from "../Restoran/Restoran.module.css"
```

Also , check the path as ,if you are working on Restoran.js then

```
"../../components/Restoran/Restoran"
```

.. -> changes to root and then from there you can change your folder and access the required components.

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect relative path (in Restorans.js), **try:**

`import Restoran from "../../components/Restoran/Restoran";`

Also you can set up [aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132624/how-to-add-import-shortcuts-alias) to have absolute paths (import Restoran from '@components/Restoran/Restoran')

Answer (score 0):

Defining the path as `'./../../components/Restoran/Restoran'`  should help.