# Absolute import using Webpack resolve.alias in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, path

I'm working on a React app that's NOT built with `create-react-app` and trying to work with Webpack to make absolute imports work. The app structure looks like this:

```
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── actions
│   ├── components
│   │   └── App.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── reducers
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── storage
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── store.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

The reason I have the `store.js` file and also the `storage` directory is because the absolute import is not working (that's why I'm making it work by relative importing from `store.js`). The following is what I'm doing in my `webpack.config.js` for the absolute import, as per their docs and other SO threads:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        },
        extensions: ['.js']
},
```

However, I keep getting the following error despite adding the rule:

```
ERROR in ./src/storage/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reducers' in '/my-project/src/storage'
```

I'm simply doing an `import rootReducer from './reducers';` from the `storage/index.js` file, where the error is coming from. What would be a good way to configure the webpack.alias object correctly in this case?

Comment: It should be `import rootReducer from '../reducers';`.

Comment: thanks, it's still broken though. I want to do just `reducers` and not `../reducers`. Implmenting absolute import would let me do that.

Comment: You are using webpack alias. In that case you should import it with the alias name `import rootReducer from 'src/reducers';`
If you want to import just `reducers` then you need to add the alias like `reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/reducers'),`

Comment: Possible duplicate [absolute imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45213279/2969544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Prakash pointed out above, here's what I needed to do:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
            reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/reducers')
        },
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code into `node_modules` in `src` directory and you can import from src as from root

```
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   └── node_modules
│       ├── actions
│       ├── components
│       │   └── App.js
│       ├── index.css
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── reducers
│       │   └── index.js
│       ├── storage
│       │   └── index.js
│       └── store.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`import App from 'components/App'`