# CRA build fail on netlify but not locally, cannot find module of local method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, build, netlify

I have an issue with netlify when attempting to deploy my site. It doesn't seem to be able to find local modules.

Here is the log:

```
12:54:43 AM: Build ready to start
12:54:45 AM: build-image version: 09c2cdcdf242cf2f57c9ee0fcad9d298fad9ad41
12:54:45 AM: build-image tag: v3.5.0
12:54:45 AM: buildbot version: 8df8a50b1177b0b57364d20e0ea150448924cebf
12:54:45 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
12:54:45 AM: Starting to download cache of 5.2MB
12:54:45 AM: Finished downloading cache in 180.688403ms
12:54:45 AM: Starting to extract cache
12:54:45 AM: Finished extracting cache in 118.246837ms
12:54:45 AM: Finished fetching cache in 304.995388ms
12:54:45 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
12:54:46 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
12:54:47 AM: Different build dir detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'client' versus '/client' in the Netlify UI
12:54:47 AM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'client/build' versus 'build' in the Netlify UI
12:54:47 AM: Starting build script
12:54:47 AM: Installing dependencies
12:54:47 AM: Python version set to 2.7
12:54:49 AM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
12:54:50 AM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
12:54:50 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
12:54:50 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
12:54:50 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
12:54:52 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
12:54:52 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
12:54:52 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
12:54:52 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
12:54:52 AM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
12:54:52 AM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
12:54:52 AM: Installing yarn at version 1.22.4
12:54:52 AM: Installing Yarn!
12:54:52 AM: > Downloading tarball...
12:54:52 AM: [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.SCC7CjcRQU
12:54:52 AM:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
12:54:52 AM:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
12:54:52 AM:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
12:54:53 AM:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
12:54:53 AM: 100    80  100    80    0     0    257      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   257
12:54:53 AM: 100    93  100    93    0     0    141      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   141
12:54:53 AM:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
12:54:53 AM: 100   643  100   643    0     0    608      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  627k
12:54:54 AM: 100 1215k  100 1215k    0     0   804k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  804k
12:54:54 AM: [2/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.SCC7CjcRQU.asc
12:54:54 AM: 100    84  100    84    0     0   3026      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3026
12:54:54 AM: 100    97  100    97    0     0   1749      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1749
12:54:54 AM: 100   647  100   647    0     0   3586      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3586
12:54:54 AM: 100  1028  100  1028    0     0   4598      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4598
12:54:54 AM: > Verifying integrity...
12:54:54 AM: gpg: Signature made Mon 09 Mar 2020 03:52:13 PM UTC using RSA key ID 69475BAA
12:54:54 AM: gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
12:54:54 AM: gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
12:54:54 AM: gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
12:54:54 AM: Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
12:54:54 AM:      Subkey fingerprint: 6D98 490C 6F1A CDDD 448E  4595 4F77 6793 6947 5BAA
12:54:54 AM: > GPG signature looks good
12:54:54 AM: > Extracting to ~/.yarn...
12:54:54 AM: > Adding to $PATH...
12:54:55 AM: > Successfully installed Yarn 1.22.4! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.
12:54:55 AM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.4
12:54:56 AM: yarn install v1.22.4
12:54:56 AM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
12:54:57 AM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
12:55:28 AM: info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
12:55:28 AM: info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
12:55:28 AM: info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
12:55:28 AM: info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
12:55:28 AM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
12:55:28 AM: warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.1.10" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > react-masonry-component@6.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > react-pdf@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > react-pdf@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.3.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "react-pdf > worker-loader@3.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > react-slick@0.27.12" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > react-slick@0.27.12" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > semantic-ui-react@2.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > semantic-ui-react@2.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.51.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.51.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.51.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.51.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.0.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.0.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning "semantic-ui-react > react-popper@2.2.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".
12:55:28 AM: warning " > slick-carousel@1.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=1.8.0".
12:55:45 AM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
12:55:49 AM: Done in 52.82s.
12:55:49 AM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
12:55:49 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
12:55:49 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
12:55:49 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:55:49 AM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:55:49 AM: Installing missing commands
12:55:49 AM: Verify run directory
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:55:51 AM:   Netlify Build                                                 
12:55:51 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ❯ Version
12:55:51 AM:   @netlify/build 5.3.3
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ❯ Flags
12:55:51 AM:   deployId: 5fc202431c76591b2b498486
12:55:51 AM:   mode: buildbot
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ❯ Current directory
12:55:51 AM:   /opt/build/repo/client
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ❯ Config file
12:55:51 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ❯ Context
12:55:51 AM:   production
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:55:51 AM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
12:55:51 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:55:51 AM: ​
12:55:51 AM: $ yarn build
12:55:52 AM: yarn run v1.22.4
12:55:52 AM: $ react-scripts build
12:55:54 AM: Creating an optimized production build...
12:56:14 AM: Failed to compile.
12:56:14 AM: 
12:56:14 AM: ./src/containers/home/HomeTitle.tsx
12:56:14 AM: Cannot find module: 'utils/userInfoFill'. Make sure this package is installed.
12:56:14 AM: You can install this package by running: yarn add utils/userInfoFill.
12:56:14 AM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
12:56:14 AM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
12:56:14 AM: ​
12:56:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:56:14 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
12:56:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:56:14 AM: ​
12:56:14 AM:   Error message
12:56:14 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn build
12:56:14 AM: ​
12:56:14 AM:   Error location
12:56:14 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:56:14 AM:   yarn build
12:56:14 AM: ​
12:56:14 AM:   Resolved config
12:56:14 AM:   build:
12:56:14 AM:     base: /opt/build/repo/client
12:56:14 AM:     command: yarn build
12:56:14 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:56:14 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/client/build
12:56:14 AM: Caching artifacts
12:56:14 AM: Started saving node modules
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving node modules
12:56:14 AM: Started saving build plugins
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving build plugins
12:56:14 AM: Started saving yarn cache
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
12:56:14 AM: Started saving pip cache
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving pip cache
12:56:14 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Started saving go dependencies
12:56:14 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:56:17 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:56:17 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:56:17 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:56:17 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m32.457785673s
```

`utils/userInfoFill` is a function I made located under `./src/utils/userInfoFill.ts` and it looks like :

```
import {userinfo} from 'data/userinfo'

export const userInfoFill = (str: string, repl_string?: string) => {
  if (repl_string) {
    const re = new RegExp("%userinfo%", "g");
    return str.replace(re, repl_string);
  } else {
        const re = new RegExp("%userinfo%", "g");
    return str.replace(re, userinfo.title_name);
  }
};
```

I'm importing it in HomeTitle.tsx with `import { userInfoFill } from "utils/userInfoFill";` I was wondering if netlify had issues with absolute paths being used but I'm not quite sure.

My tsconfig.json looks like :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Where adding `"baseUrl": "src"` was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213279/how-to-avoid-using-relative-path-imports-redux-action-action1-in-cre). To allow for absolute url references

The file structure of the project is:

```
/
 ┣ client
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ public
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ components
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ containers
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ home
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ HomeTitle.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ data
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ temp
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ userinfo.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ pages
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Home.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ utils
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ userInfoFill.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ userInfoFill.unit.test.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ App.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┣ .eslintrc
 ┃ ┣ .tsconfig.json
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┗ ...
 ┣ server
 ┗ ...
```

I can build and host the server locally just fine so I'm not sure if there's some netlify setting I need?

Here are my current build settings too:
[image: Current netlify settings]

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer. It turns out windows was showing `userInfoFill.ts` but git was saving the file as `UserInfoFill.ts`. I'm not entirely sure why this happened but I solved it by renaming the files on git and now netlify deploys.