# @ alternative of vuejs for react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am newbie in react, so far loving it.My question is a bit different.
When we work on vuejs we have a pointer to our src folder which we use with **@**
e.g

```
import Button '@/components/button'
```

I've searched a lot but cant find an alternative for this in react, so in my current application i have to import like

```
import Products from '../../components/products/Products'
```

which makes the code looks like a mess if we have multiple components in a single component, do we have a implementation of **@** of vuejs in react?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45213279/10321531) will help you, you must set up some babel config for your project